# antd table scroll to top when click Pagination

Tags: javascript, antd

This is my table code in AntD, on pagination clicked

```js
<Table
        columns={fixedColumns}
        dataSource={fixedData}
        pagination={false}
        scroll={{ x: 2000, y: 500 }}
        bordered
        summary={() => (
          <Table.Summary fixed>
            <Table.Summary.Row>
              <Table.Summary.Cell index={0}>Summary</Table.Summary.Cell>
              <Table.Summary.Cell index={1}>
                This is a summary content
              </Table.Summary.Cell>
            </Table.Summary.Row>
          </Table.Summary>
        )}
      />
```

I want it to scroll to page top.

Comment: My Solution : [Codesandbox ][1]
 [1]: https://codesandbox.io/s/summary-antd-5-7-2-forked-qmtwj4?file=/demo.tsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following code to scroll to the top of the page.

```js
const handleChangePage = () => {
  window.scrollTo({ top: 0, left: 0, behavior: "smooth" });
};
```

In the above code, I have used the `window.scrollTo` method to scroll to the top of the page when the pagination is clicked. The `handlePaginationChange` function is passed to the `onChange` prop of the AntD `Table` component to handle pagination changes.

Please check the following code. This is the same code that you have added to [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/summary-antd-5-7-2-forked-qmtwj4?file=/demo.tsx), but with the scrolling issue fixed.

App.tsx

```js
import React from "react";
import "./index.css";
import { Table, Typography, Pagination } from "antd";
import type { ColumnsType } from "antd/es/table";

const { Text } = Typography;

interface DataType {
  key: string;
  name: string;
  borrow: number;
  repayment: number;
}

interface FixedDataType {
  key: React.Key;
  name: string;
  description: string;
}

const columns: ColumnsType<DataType> = [
  {
    title: "Name",
    dataIndex: "name"
  },
  {
    title: "Borrow",
    dataIndex: "borrow"
  },
  {
    title: "Repayment",
    dataIndex: "repayment"
  }
];

const data: DataType[] = [
  {
    key: "1",
    name: "John Brown",
    borrow: 10,
    repayment: 33
  },
  {
    key: "2",
    name: "Jim Green",
    borrow: 100,
    repayment: 0
  },
  {
    key: "3",
    name: "Joe Black",
    borrow: 10,
    repayment: 10
  },
  {
    key: "4",
    name: "Jim Red",
    borrow: 75,
    repayment: 45
  }
];

const fixedColumns: ColumnsType<FixedDataType> = [
  {
    title: "Name",
    dataIndex: "name",
    fixed: true,
    width: 100
  },
  {
    title: "Description",
    dataIndex: "description"
  }
];

const fixedData: FixedDataType[] = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i += 1) {
  fixedData.push({
    key: i,
    name: ["Light", "Bamboo", "Little"][i % 3],
    description: "Everything that has a beginning, has an end."
  });
}

const App: React.FC = () => {
  
  const handleChangePage = () => {
    window.scrollTo({ top: 0, left: 0, behavior: "smooth" });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Table
        columns={columns}
        dataSource={data}
        pagination={false}
        bordered
        summary={(pageData) => {
          let totalBorrow = 0;
          let totalRepayment = 0;

          pageData.forEach(({ borrow, repayment }) => {
            totalBorrow += borrow;
            totalRepayment += repayment;
          });

          return (
            <>
              <Table.Summary.Row>
                <Table.Summary.Cell index={0}>Total</Table.Summary.Cell>
                <Table.Summary.Cell index={1}>
                  <Text type="danger">{totalBorrow}</Text>
                </Table.Summary.Cell>
                <Table.Summary.Cell index={2}>
                  <Text>{totalRepayment}</Text>
                </Table.Summary.Cell>
              </Table.Summary.Row>
              <Table.Summary.Row>
                <Table.Summary.Cell index={0}>Balance</Table.Summary.Cell>
                <Table.Summary.Cell index={1} colSpan={2}>
                  <Text type="danger">{totalBorrow - totalRepayment}</Text>
                </Table.Summary.Cell>
              </Table.Summary.Row>
            </>
          );
        }}
      />

      <br />

      <Table
        columns={fixedColumns}
        dataSource={fixedData}
        pagination={false}
        scroll={{ x: 2000, y: 500 }}
        bordered
        summary={() => (
          <Table.Summary fixed>
            <Table.Summary.Row>
              <Table.Summary.Cell index={0}>Summary</Table.Summary.Cell>
              <Table.Summary.Cell index={1}>
                This is a summary content
              </Table.Summary.Cell>
            </Table.Summary.Row>
          </Table.Summary>
        )}
      />
      <Pagination
        onChange={handleChangePage}
        pageSize={15}
        total={fixedData.length}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: thanks, I figured out how to solve the problem when I posted the question, but I can't comment it in the comments